# Найти номер первой из строк, не содержащих ни одного положительного элемента

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, матрицы

Есть матрица M x N, нужно найти  номер первой из строк, не содержащих ни одного положительного элемента.Спасибо! Застрял...

Comment: Используете вложенные циклы, если не знаете стандартные алгоритмы. В чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этой демонстрационной программе показано, как найти в матрице строку, не содержащую ни одного положительного элемента, с помощью стандартных алгоритмов и обычных циклов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 20;
    const size_t N = 6;

    int a[M][N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int &x : row ) x = std::rand() % int( M * N ) - int( M * N / 2 );
    }

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    auto all_non_positive = []( const auto &row )
    {
        return std::none_of( std::begin( row ), std::end( row ), 
                             std::bind2nd( std::greater<int>(), 0 ) );
    };

    auto it = std::find_if( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), all_non_positive );

    if ( it == std::end( a ) )
    {
        std::cout << "There is no row that does not contain positive numbers" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Row #" << std::distance( std::begin( a ), it )
                  << " contains only non-positive numbers" << std::endl;
    }

    bool found = false;
    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; not found && i < M; i += not found )
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j < N && a[i][j] <= 0 ) ++j;

        found = j == N;
    }

    if ( not found )
    {
        std::cout << "There is no row that does not contain positive numbers" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Row #" << i
                  << " contains only non-positive numbers" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом

```
-46   8 -10 -48  -6 -44 
 49  46 -35 -21   9 -41 
 50   7  27  31  -4 -38 
 21 -13  47 -52  35 -27 
 53  19 -22 -17  54  48 
-58 -60  -4 -16 -55  42 
  0  54  21  17 -27 -30 
 28 -44  29 -12  39 -43 
 10   0   4 -11   0 -20 
 22  -7  59  53  28  45 
 41  30  46 -31 -54  51 
-48  -1  37  33 -44 -58 
 55  45 -42  24 -27  57 
 34  35 -11 -22 -36  49 
 18  39 -25   9  32 -57 
 -5   5  26 -19  34  32 
-36  38 -37 -59   3 -20 
-57 -10 -43 -46 -53 -18 
-57  41 -43 -15 -41 -27 
-26  30 -56   9 -21  28 
Row #17 contains only non-positive numbers
Row #17 contains only non-positive numbers
```